# Wait the end of forEach loop to render - Javascript

Tags: javascript, node.js

i was reading about how to solve this problem, and everyone says that i should use "async" and "await", but i dont know how to put it propely on my code. (I'm making a new JSON, and i should send it to the front-end, but i need to wait to the JSON get ready inside the forEach loop first, then render on the screen).

```
router.get('/',  (req, res) => {
 Controle.find().lean().then( (controles) => {

 var controles_cadastrados = []    
 controles.forEach((controle, index, array)=>{
  
   Sensor.find({id_mac: controle.sensor}).lean().then((sensor)=>{
       controle.sensor_nome = sensor[0].nome

       Atuador.find({id_mac: controle.atuador}).lean().then((atuador)=>{

         controle.atuador_nome = atuador[0].nome
         controles_cadastrados.push(controle)
        
         console.log(controles_cadastrados)

       })

   })
 })
 //wait to send the response
 res.render('controle/controles', {controles: controles_cadastrados })

 }).catch((erro) => {
  console.log('Erro ao carregar controles')
 })
})
```

I have try it in so many ways, but none seens to working good.
Sorry if i made some mistake.

Answer (score 2):

You aren't properly waiting for all your asynchronous operations to be done before calling `res.render()` thus your array is empty or partially populated when you try to use it.  So, you need to use the promises to be able to track when everything is done.

You have a couple choices.   You can run all your request in parallel or in sequence.  I'll show an example of both:

Here's processing all the database requests in parallel.  This chains the various promises and use `Promise.all()` to know when they are all done.  Results in the `controles_cadastrados` are not in any particular order, but this will probably run quicker than processing everything sequentially.

```
router.get('/', (req, res) => {
    Controle.find()
        .lean()
        .then(controles => {
            const controles_cadastrados = [];
            Promise.all(controles.map(controle => {
                return Sensor.find({ id_mac: controle.sensor })
                    .lean()
                    .then(sensor => {
                        controle.sensor_nome = sensor[0].nome;
                        return Atuador.find({ id_mac: controle.atuador })
                            .lean()
                            .then(atuador => {
                                controle.atuador_nome = atuador[0].nome;
                                controles_cadastrados.push(controle);

                                console.log(controles_cadastrados);
                            });
                    });
            })).then(() => {
                //wait to send the response
                res.render('controle/controles', {
                    controles: controles_cadastrados,
                });
            });
        }).catch(erro => {
            console.log('Erro ao carregar controles');
            res.sendStatus(500);
        });
});
```

And, here's how you would sequence the operations using `async/await`:

```
router.get('/', async (req, res) => {
    try {
        let controles = await Controle.find().lean();
        const controles_cadastrados = [];
        for (let controle of controles) {
            let sensor = await Sensor.find({ id_mac: controle.sensor }).lean();
            controle.sensor_nome = sensor[0].nome;
            let atuador = await Atuador.find({ id_mac: controle.atuador }).lean()
            controle.atuador_nome = atuador[0].nome;
            controles_cadastrados.push(controle);
            console.log(controles_cadastrados);
        }
        //wait to send the response
        res.render('controle/controles', {
            controles: controles_cadastrados,
        });
    } catch(e) {
        console.log(e, 'Erro ao carregar controles');
        res.sendStatus(500);        
    }
});
```

Also, note that all possible rejected promises or other errors are captured here and a response is always sent to the incoming http request, even when there's an error.

Comment: Thank you! Nice explanation and worked like a charm.  Best regards.

Comment: @Donada  - If this answered your question, then you can indicate that to the community by clicking the checkmark to the left of the answer.  That will also earn you some reputation points here for following the proper procedure.