# How to move all object into an array and send using res.json in node js

Tags: javascript, node.js, json

Hey guys am trying to loop through an array to get all user data of a particular user using node js and mongodb from another table of information, so each of the element of that array can return a data from the other table. so far if i run my code and console.log it returns all the user data but if i use res.json it returns just 1 data please how do i return all the data using res.json?, can i move all the object into just 1 array if yes please how do i solve it

**my code**

```
//get students that offer the course and send link to them
router.get('/send/Link/:id',GetAllUserdata,async(req,res)=>{
    const {dept,college,level} = req.body
    const responseArray = [];
 
        for (let index = 0; index < res.GetUserDT.coursesHandled.length; index++) {
           responseArray.push( res.GetUserDT.coursesHandled[index].courseCode); 
        }
        responseArray.map(async(course,i)=>{
          const getActiveClass = await Class.findOne({'school.college':college,'school.department':dept,'school.level':level,'school.course':course,'type':'uploadclass',"expires":0})
        if(getActiveClass){
        console.log({url:getActiveClass.address,course:getActiveClass.school.course})
        }else{
            res.status(404).json('nothing')
        }
           
        })
})
```

**my console answer**

```
{ url: 'eyaF8Pq6SP8e7YMe48aY', course: 'csc2101' }
{ url: 'c6d8KGfo6WO67QRC0Dq8', course: 'csc2104' }
```

**my res.json answer**

```
{ url: 'eyaF8Pq6SP8e7YMe48aY', course: 'csc2101' }
```

Comment: An answer from a very similar question just a few hours ago: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63893478/wait-the-end-of-foreach-loop-to-render-javascript/63893517#63893517.  From that, you can see how to solve this.  Your `.map()` generates an array of promises.  You need to use `Promise.all()` on that array to know when all those promises are done.  `.map()` by itself is not promise-aware.

Answer (score 0):

i'd recommend you to save the results into array and return the array at the end. try to use try catch block to catch the async call errors.

```js
 const {dept,college,level} = req.body
    const responseArray = [];
let result=[];
 
        for (let index = 0; index < res.GetUserDT.coursesHandled.length; index++) {
           responseArray.push( res.GetUserDT.coursesHandled[index].courseCode); 
        }
try{
        responseArray.map(async(course,i)=>{
          const getActiveClass = await Class.findOne({'school.college':college,'school.department':dept,'school.level':level,'school.course':course,'type':'uploadclass',"expires":0})
        if(getActiveClass){
        result.push({url:getActiveClass.address,course:getActiveClass.school.course})
        }
        })
return res.json(result);
}
catch(error){
            res.status(404).json('nothing')

}
```