# Remove duplicates from Handlebars output

Tags: javascript, node.js, handlebars.js

I am looping through some messages. Each message has the following schema:
[image]

With handlebars I loop through each of the messages and if the fromUser.id is not equal to the 'CurrentUser' or if toUser.id is not equal to CurrentUser, I return the the list.
This is the code:

```
{{#each messages}}
   {{#notEqual fromUser.id ../CurrentUser}}
      <tr>
         <td><a href="/my-account/messages/{{_id}}">{{fromUser.firstName}}</a></td>
      </tr>
   {{/notEqual}}
   {{#notEqual toUser.id ../CurrentUser}}
      <tr>
         <td><a href="/my-account/messages/{{_id}}">{{toUser.firstName}}</a></td>
      </tr>
   {{/notEqual}}
{{/each}}
```

This code renders:
[image]

My #notEqual handlebars helper looks like:

```
notEqual: function(a, b, options) {
        if(a != b) {
            return options.fn(this);
        }
        return options.inverse(this);
    }
```

Now, as you can see, I this renders four times the user 'Christian'. Is there any way I can remove duplicates with a custom handlebars function, so that the user 'Christian' displays only once?

I tried looping through each message in my router.get function to build the logic in there, but I get stuck with res.render within the forEach loops, which doesn't work. However, the following code also doesn't remove any duplicates... So I thought working this with handlebars would do the trick, but I don't know how.

```
router.get('/my-account/messages', userAuthenticated, (req, res)=> {
    Message.find({$or: [{fromUser: req.user.id}, {toUser: req.user.id}]})
    .populate('fromUser')
    .populate('toUser')
    .then(messages => {
        messages.forEach(message => {
            User.find({$or: [{_id: message.fromUser._id}, {_id: message.toUser._id}]})
            .where('_id').ne(req.user.id)
            .then(users => {
                res.render('home/my-account/messages', {messages: messages, users: users, CurrentUser: req.user.id}); // Throws the error: Cannot set headers after they are sent to the client
            })      
        })
    })
});
```

Comment: It sounds to me that you are trying to put logic into your template that would be better suited to be used in your database query.

Answer (score 0):

I managed to add the logic to the router.get() with the help of [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63893478/wait-the-end-of-foreach-loop-to-render-javascript).

This works nicely:

```
router.get('/my-account/messages', userAuthenticated, (req, res)=> {
   Message.find({$or: [{fromUser: req.user.id}, {toUser: req.user.id}]})
   .populate('fromUser')
   .populate('toUser')
   .then(messages => {
       const usersArray = [];
       Promise.all(messages.map(message => {
           return User.find({$or: [{_id: message.fromUser._id}, {_id: message.toUser._id}]})
           .where('_id').ne(req.user.id)
           .then(user => {
               let userId = user[0]._id
               usersArray.push(userId.toString());
           })
       }))
       .then(() => {
           let uniqueUsersArray = usersArray.filter((v, i, a) => a.indexOf(v) === i);
        User.find({_id: uniqueUsersArray})
           .then(users => {
               console.log(users);
               res.render('home/my-account/messages', {messages: messages, users: users});
           });
       });
   });
```

});

And the handlebars part is as simple as this:

```
{{#each users}}
   <tr>
      <td><a href="/my-account/messages/{{_id}}">{{firstName}}</a></td>
      </tr>
{{/each}}
```